# Dynamically populating ID field in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

I am puzzled and confused!
I have these columns in a form

ID | Name | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 | Total

How to populate/autofill the **ID** column dynamically/automatically(Like 1,2,3 and so on as the user fills the form) so that user doesn't need to enter it manually. I have also installed Gravity forms sticky list to display entries. I am a newbie to Wordpress and Gravity forms, please help!

Comment: Your question is bit unclear little more information would be helpful

Comment: @madforstrength,  More like this [Image](https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/c4ed/kacv0hsfrrvdrv54g.jpg)

Comment: Could someone help please! Also how to insert floating scrollbar like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/) into wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

The entry ID is sequential across all forms. If you're looking for sequential IDs per form, you might be interested in my [GP Unique ID](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-unique-id/) plugin.

Comment: Auto increment field is what I need.